# Android Navigation Deep Link Nested Navigation automatic backstack

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have been looking into essentially deep linking/navigation directly into any page within an application.  There are many use cases for this but one for example is a registration process where I want users to be able to skip to certain pages but still allow the backstack to work.  To give an explicit example
MainFragment -> RegistrationFragment1 -> RegistrationFragment2 -> RegistrationFragment3 ->RegistrationFragment4 -> RegistrationFragment5
I want to be able to open directly to any of those pages and have the backstack work just like the above.  I have an example repo here with an example of that
https://github.com/DavidCorrado/AndroidNavigation

So from my understanding there are a few ways I can manage that.  I would like to do something with navigation with nested navigation graphs that provide this via xml and nesting navigation.  Basically like this article
https://medium.com/swlh/proper-back-stack-on-android-every-time-4a811f8ab78c

Problem I have is the above article works with creating a pending intent via a notification and that does work but I do not think I should be using pending intents everywhere for any navigation.

I want to just deep link via uri or via some other way with graph and destination.  I would imagine there is just something I am missing.

Below is a MainFragment where I link to all of the different things I tried
https://github.com/DavidCorrado/AndroidNavigation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/navigation/ui/main/MainFragment.kt

btn_reg5 is the pending intent which does provide proper backstack but I imagine I should find a way to do this without a pending intent.

All other buttons do not work.

Comment: Hi bro. I am looking for the solution for this like you. Have you found out any best way to deal with it ?

Comment: Not really.  I actually went another path and thought about if we need to deep link and have it keep the navigation.  I found we did not need the backstack.  I did not find a clean way to do this.